# Close() was never explicity called on database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that stores coordinates for my Google maps. It works fine but in my logcat i recieve this error:

```
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.androidbasic12/databases/android_api' 
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:2072)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1083)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1170)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:844)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:231)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at com.example.androidbasic12.library.DatabaseHandler.getLatLng(DatabaseHandler.java:153)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at com.example.androidbasic12.library.UserFunctions.getCoords(UserFunctions.java:124)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at com.example.androidbasic12.map.onCreate(map.java:61)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/SQLiteDatabase(12337):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 14:36:24.338: E/System(12337): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2230)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2322)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2318)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2283)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:2043)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
01-25 14:36:24.343: E/System(12337):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I understand that there's somewhere I haven't closed my database connection after using it, problem is where the error points at it seems I did indeed close it.

*userFunctions.class*

```
    public String getUsername(Context context, String uname) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.getUsername();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor != null){
        uname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    }
    cursor.close();     
    db.close();
    return uname;

    }


    /**
 * Get lat and lng from TABLE_CARCOORDS
 */
public ArrayList<String> getCoords(Context context, String lat, String lng) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.getLatLng();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        ArrayList<String> cordarr = new ArrayList<String>();
        lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
        lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
        cordarr.add(lat);
        cordarr.add(lng);
        return cordarr; 

    }
cursor.close();
db.close();
return null;
}
```

*databasehandler.class*

```
    public Cursor getUsername(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN + " WHERE name = " + KEY_NAME);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getLatLng(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARCOORD + " WHERE name = " + CAR_KEY_NAME);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;

}
```

*Finally, map.class*

```
public class map extends FragmentActivity{
private static LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.88,151.21);
public static  LatLng sala = new LatLng(59.91602, 16.594108);
int travel = 0;
int MapTypeInt = 0;
private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
String username;

String Lat1;
String Lng1;
Double lat;
Double lng;
ProgressDialog dialog;

// JSON response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_LAT = "lat";
private static String KEY_LNG = "lng";

String errorhandler = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    new getCord().execute();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    UserFunctions userFunc = new UserFunctions();
    ArrayList<String> cordarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    cordarr = userFunc.getCoords(getApplicationContext(), Lat1, Lng1);
    if(cordarr != null && cordarr.size()> 1 ){
        Log.d("LOG", "I got lat long");
        Lat1 = cordarr.get(0);
        Lng1 = cordarr.get(1);
        lat = goDouble(Lat1);
        lng  = goDouble(Lng1);
        LatLng sala = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sala).title("Coords: " 
        + lat + ", "
        + lng));

    } else {
        Log.d("LOG", "no lat long found");
    }



    //Button that sends the user to Sala by default, and to Sydney if Sala
    Button btnSyd =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSyd);
    btnSyd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stu

            if (travel == 0){
                travelToSala();
                travel = 1;
            } else if (travel == 1) {
                travelToSydney();
                travel = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    //Button for setting map type to satellite if normal, to normal if satellite
    final ImageButton changeBtn =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changeBtn);
    changeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeMapType(changeBtn);
        }
    });     
}
//method that changes maptype
private void changeMapType(ImageButton button){
    if(MapTypeInt == 0){
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_map);
        MapTypeInt = 1;
    } else if (MapTypeInt == 1) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.satellite);
        MapTypeInt = 0;
    }
}
//Function that travels user to Sydney
private void travelToSydney(){
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, 15));
    Button btnSyd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSyd);
    btnSyd.setText("travel to Sala");
}
//Function that travels user to Sala
private void travelToSala(){
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sala, 15));
    Button btnSyd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSyd);
    btnSyd.setText("travel to Sydney!");
}
//Checks if map is setup, and if it isn't, set's up the map
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sala, 15));
        options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
        .compassEnabled(true)
        .rotateGesturesEnabled(true)
        .tiltGesturesEnabled(true);
        if(mMap != null){
            //The map is veriefied
        }
    } 


}
//method input string, output double
public Double goDouble(String Latlng) {
    Double goDouble = Double.parseDouble(Latlng);
    return goDouble;
}

class getCord extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        username = userFunction.getUsername(getApplicationContext(), "uname"); 
        JSONObject json = userFunction.getCarcoord(username);

        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null){
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res)==1){
                    //Successfully found users car coordinates
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_coord = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    //clear previous entries in table "TABLE_COORD"
                    userFunction.resetCarcoord(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addCoord(json_coord.getString(KEY_NAME), json_coord.getString(KEY_LAT), json_coord.getString(KEY_LNG));
                    errorhandler = "2";

                }
            } else if(json.getString(KEY_ERROR) != null) {
                String res = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    //Some error in getting registration, should not happen though
                    errorhandler = "1";
                }

            }

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(map.this,
                   "Loading car coordinats", "Please wait ...", true, true);
        super.onPreExecute();       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(errorhandler == "1"){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User has not got car", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            errorhandler = "";
        } else if (errorhandler == "2" ) {
            // Error in login
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Successfully got coords for car", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            errorhandler = "";
        }
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

}

Sorry if there's a lot of unrelated code!

Answer (score 0):

You have to close every single DatabaseHelper (`DatabaseHandler` in your case) instance.

The best way, to avoid doing this, is only to use one single DatabaseHandler for your whole application.

This is the relevant code for it, to achieve the above described goal:

```
public static DatabaseHandler sInstance;

    public static synchronized DatabaseHandler getHandler(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
```

Comment: Weirdly, it was enough to call `db.close();` in `userFunctions.class` , that removed the error. When I tried to close the database connection in the DatabaseHandler.class, I got an error saying that the database already had been closed.

Comment: Yeah, calling `db.close();` is enough, but if you want stable and reliable code I suggest you the method I mentioned above.